# Creating cumulative anisotropic cost surface using altitude and landcover

Tags: r, gis, distance

I would like to compute a cumulative cost (in time) surface from a number of points of interest (n~150) over my area and then extract the value of the cost raster for other GPS coordinates (~70,000). Thus, my ultimate goal is to get an estimate of travel time for each GPS coordinate to the nearest point of interest. Two resistance measures for each cell need to be considered: altitude and land cover. I am using the package gdistance and Tobler's hiking function. I have gotten other estimates from GRASS (using the Naismith-Langmuir algorithm) and [AccessMod](https://www.accessmod.org/). The estimates differ from the GRASS implementation as I would expect due to using a different algorithm, but they should not differ much from the AccessMod estimates because I've tried to replicate their method as closely as possible from reading the manual. However, the average difference between gdistance estimates and AcessMod estimates is around 20 minutes and the max difference is 3 hours.

Would anyone be willing to review my code and suggest edits that may explain the discrepancy? I've recreated my code using a public and simplified dataset.

```
library(gdistance)
library(sp)

# load DEM and create polygon to build example
dem <- raster(system.file("external/maungawhau.grd", package="gdistance"))
e <- extent(dem); crs <- projection(dem)
poly <- as(e, 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(poly) <- crs
# points of interest
set.seed(1)
poi <- spsample(poly, 10, type="random")
# GPS locations of "ending" points
ends <- spsample(poly, 50, type="random")
#confirm creation of sample points
plot(dem)
points(poi, col="red")
points(ends, col="blue")

# create slope friction layer from DEM
altDiff <- function(x) {x[2]-x[1]}
hd <- transition(dem, altDiff, 8, symm=FALSE)
slope <- geoCorrection(hd)

# create landcover friction layer
lc <- raster(replicate(61,sample(1:5,87,rep=TRUE))) #landcover layer categorized by class
wlk <- data.frame(class = c(1,2,3,4,5), wlkspeed = c(0.66,0.25,0.25,2.7,3.4)) #walking speed (m/s) on flat ground for each landcover class
lc_friction <- subs(lc, wlk, by=1, which=2) #create resistance raster of speeds
lc_T <- transition(lc_friction, function(x) 1/mean(x), 8, symm=FALSE) 

#calculate Tobler's hiking function for each cell and its neighboring 8 cells then build cumulative cost surface and extract value at each "end"
adj <- adjacent(dem, cells=1:ncell(dem), pairs=TRUE, directions=8)
speed <- slope
speed[adj] <- lc_T[adj]*exp(-3.5*abs(slope[adj] + 0.05)) #Tobler's function with corrected walking speed as coefficient
conductance <- geoCorrection(speed)
access <- accCost(conductance, poi)
access[!is.finite(access)] <- NA
summary(values(access))
access_ends <- extract(access, ends)
seconds <- access_ends
minutes <- access_ends/60

#plot result
plot(access)
points(poi, col="red")
points(ends, col="blue")
```